# Make checkbox array stay checked after submitting the form

Tags: php, forms, checkbox

I create a large form of checkboxes that get their values from the database. The problem is, I need to find a way how to make the browser remember that certain checkboxes were checked. After submitting the form, it posts the values and another function uses the post values for another function.

**So this is how I create my checkbox form:**

```
$query .= "SELECT id, ediens FROM menu_edieni_otrie";
    $query1 .= "SELECT id, ediens FROM menu_edieni_zupas";

    echo "<body>\n";
    echo "<form name='otrie_edieni' action='' method='post'>\n";
    echo "<table border='1px'>\n";
    echo "<tr>\n";
    echo "<td>\n";
    /* execute multi query */
    if ($mysqli->multi_query($query)) {
        if ($result = $mysqli->store_result()) {
            while ($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
            echo "<input type='checkbox' name='ediens2[]' value='";
            printf ("%s", $row[1]);
            echo "' ";
            echo "/>";
            printf ("%s </br>\n ", $row[1]);
            }
            $result->free();
        }
    }
    echo "</td>\n";
    echo "<td>\n";
    if ($mysqli->multi_query($query1)) {
        if ($result = $mysqli->store_result()) {
            while ($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
            echo "<input type='checkbox' name='zupas2[]' value='";
            printf ("%s", $row[1]);
            echo "'/>";
            printf ("%s </br>\n ", $row[1]);
            }
            $result->free();
        }
    }
    echo "</td>\n";
    echo "</tr>\n";
    echo "</table>";
    echo "<input type='submit' name='formSubmit' value='Submit' />";
    echo "</form>\n";
    echo "</body>";
```

How can I check what checkboxes where checked after the submit button is pressed and leave them checked afterwards - after refresh?

The _POST is received by this function:

```
$ediens2 = $_POST['ediens2'];
$zupas2 = $_POST['zupas2'];
  if(empty($ediens2) && empty($zupas2)) 
  {
    echo("Nav ievadīta neviena vērtība");
  } 
  else
  {
    $N = count($ediens2);
    $M = count($zupas2);
    $mysqli = @new mysqli('*', '*', '*', '*');

        $mysqli->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'", $connection);

        if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
            die('Connect Error: ' . $mysqli->connect_errno);
        }
    for($i=0; $i < $N; $i++){
        $query3 = "UPDATE tmp_cirks SET name='$ediens2[$i]' WHERE id='$i'";
        $mysqli->multi_query($query3);
    }
    /* close connection */
    $mysqli->close();
    $date = date('d/m/Y', time());
    echo $date;
    echo("<br>");
    echo("<ul>");
    for($i=0; $i < $N; $i++)
    {
        echo("<li>");
        echo("<strong>" . $ediens2[$i] . "</strong>");
        echo("</li>");
    }
    echo("</ul>");
    echo("<ul>");
    for($i=0; $i < $M; $i++)
    {
        echo("<li>");
        echo("<strong>" . $zupas2[$i] . "</strong>");
        echo("</li>");
    }
    echo("</ul>");      
  }
```

What I have figured out so far, is that I store the values received from the _POST to a separate database table - with this:

```
for($i=0; $i < $N; $i++){
        $query3 = "UPDATE tmp_cirks SET name='$ediens2[$i]' WHERE id='$i'";
        $mysqli->multi_query($query3);
    }
```

I was thinking that then I could compare if the generated checkbox form has any values stored in this separate table. If it has - then it makes the "checked='checked'" function. Am I on the right track?

The database tables look like this:
id  ediens  edieni_ru   edieni_eng  cena    cena_puse
otr1    Kotletes    Котлеты Сutlet  2,00    1,30
otr2    Gulašs  Гуляш   Goulash 2,20    1,40
otr3    Slinkie tīteņi  Ленивые голубцы Chopped cabbage with fried minced meat  1,70    1,15
otr4    Plovs   Плов    Pilaff  1,70    1,15

to generate the checkbox values I use only the "**ediens**" column.
The new table that I have created looks like this (the one that saves the values).

id  name
1   Kotletes
2   Gulašs
3   Karbonāde

so what I was thinking is, something like this:
if (name==ediens) echo 'checked=checked'; (of course this is just a not working example)

any suggestions? I have no idea if I am even on the right track.

Thank you in advance for the help!

Comment: As you are saving them to db there must me Primary key for the submitted value you can keep that in a session key and can retrieve the value after page refresh occur.

Comment: I'm new to SQL coding, right now I came up with a solution, but have no idea on how to realize it. What I did, is store the checked data in a tmp database table, and I want to compare on page load if the values in tmp database equal any of the checkbox values. If it does - it makes the checked="checked" attribute. 

The thing is I am not really sure on how to compare the two database tables in an php "if" statement.

Comment: Do you want to 'remember' the last menu settings for the user and the next time the user visits your web-site, even if it is hours later, they see their last menu selections?

Comment: Yeah well, it would be great if it would remember it even after another log-in. I have everything working now as I planned, although the user has to keep the window open in order not to "delete" it's previous selections. How can I manage to store the data? Should I use a temporary database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All working here... Any issues then please ask. I will fix them.

This code displays two menus from entries stored in two tables. It allows the user to select the entries that they wish and persists the 'checked' items by setting the 'checked' attribute on the output screen by checking the $_POST array.

It is the supplied code debugged and made to work with minimal changes.

Fixes: 
1) the 'multi_query' didn't process the second result set correctly.

2) The separate SQL queries need to be terminated with a ';'.

Here is the tested code (PHP 5.3.18).

I changed the 'fetch' statements so i could access the data by 'column names'.

I have left the debugging code in that shows the $_POST array so that you can see it working. Just delete the code marked /* debug */ to stop them displaying.

```
<?php
    /* debug */ var_dump($_POST);

    $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'test', 'test', 'testmysql');

    $query  = '';
    $query .= "SELECT id, ediens FROM menu_edieni_otrie order by id;";

    $query .= "SELECT id, ediens FROM menu_edieni_zupas order by id;";

    echo "<body>\n";
    echo "<form name='otrie_edieni' action='' method='post'>\n";
    echo "<table border='1px'>\n";
    echo "<tr>\n";
    echo "<td>\n";
    /* execute multi query */
    if ($mysqli->multi_query($query)) {
        if ($result = $mysqli->store_result()) {

            while ($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
                echo "<input type='checkbox' name='ediens2[]' value='";
                printf ("%s", $row['id']);
                echo "' ";
                echo isset($_POST['ediens2']) && in_array($row['id'], $_POST['ediens2']) ? ' checked="checked"' : '';
                echo "/>";
                printf ("%s </br>\n ", $row[1]);
            }
            $result->free();
        }
    }

    echo "</td>\n";
    echo "<td>\n";
    // try and get the next results (zupas)

    if ($mysqli->more_results()) {          // any results from the zupas menu?
        $mysqli->next_result();             // get them...
        $result = $mysqli->store_result();  // access them...

        while ($row = $result->fetch_array()) { // process them
            echo "<input type='checkbox' name='zupas2[]' value='";
            printf ("%s", $row['id']);
            echo "' ";
            // we need to set the 'checked' attribute if the user ticked the box.
            // we check the $_POST array to see if the current value is in there ans set it checked if it is.
            echo isset($_POST['zupas2']) && in_array($row['id'], $_POST['zupas2']) ? ' checked="checked"' : '';
            echo "'/>";
            printf ("%s </br>\n ", $row[1]);
        }
        $result->free();
    }
    echo "</td>\n";
    echo "</tr>\n";
    echo "</table>";
    echo "<input type='submit' name='formSubmit' value='Submit' />";
    echo "</form>\n";
    echo "</body>";
?>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Although It doesn't seem to want to work for me. I checked out your suggested code, but after trying to sort it out this way - I still fail and the checkboxes are unchecked after the refresh.

Comment: ok, i haven't tested your code as i don't know your table definitions or have sample data. However, i suspect that there are other faults in your code. don't panic! It isn't far off. Are you easily able to post youir tables and some sample data? If you can't i will create something that matches your tables. And you will at least see it working in principle.

Comment: @nSage, no need for more information! I will post the working code shortly!

Comment: Ouh.. well edited my post any way, it has more info now, hope it makes it more clear.

Comment: It is working perfectly now! Thank you very much, will need to work more on my php skills.

Answer (score 0):

Use [setcookie](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php) in the post function and $_COOKIE after refresh to determine if it was checked.

```
setcookie("Checkbox1", "checked", time()+3600);
if($_COOKIE["Checkbox1"] == "checked") echo "checkbox1 checked";
```

EDIT: But, of course, you can load the checkbox values from database, if you save them.

Comment: Cookies don't seem as a valid option, as I don't have any certain time for which the boxes should be ticked. 

Loading the values from a database seems a more valid option although I am still looking for solutions on how to do that. Not very good at SQL. Still trying to find my way through it. :)

Comment: Well, it depends on how long it is supposed to keep its data and if they are relevant to the user or the browser (session). If relevant to user (you need some id for him), use database; if not, than use session/cookies.
If it's something like filter or selection, **definitely use cookies** and set time to year for example.

EDIT: user = someone signed in; browser = someone visiting your site (even regularly)